# Multiple testing correction or not?

Tags: multiple-comparisons

I have a set of 70 individuals and 90 continuous variables measured for those individuals, and I run univariate models to test for the association to an outcome variable. Is it necessary to *always* perform multiple testing correction even in cases like these?

Please limit answers to the question in place.